# run multiple instance of same php script from bash

Tags: php, bash, cron

I am running a cron job to execute a php file multiple times per minute like this

```
*  *  *  *  * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myFile.php >> /var/www/html/cronlog 2> /dev/null
*  *  *  *  * sleep 10; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myFile.php >> /var/www/html/cronlog 2> /dev/null
*  *  *  *  * sleep 20; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myFile.php >> /var/www/html/cronlog 2> /dev/null
*  *  *  *  * sleep 30; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myFile.php >> /var/www/html/cronlog 2> /dev/null
*  *  *  *  * sleep 40; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myFile.php >> /var/www/html/cronlog 2> /dev/null
*  *  *  *  * sleep 50; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myFile.php >> /var/www/html/cronlog 2> /dev/null
```

This executes `myFile.php` fine but when i count the number of process running 
`ps -ef | grep php | wc -l` 
It adds up and cpu usage hits 100%!

Should i be running a single bash file and from within the bash file run multiple php files staggered?

If so how would I write the bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
????
????
????
```

**edit:** I would like to mention that the execution of the file should take place after the previous execution is complete.

Also a cron job is not mandatory as krisFR has pointed out

Comment: Wow, i think you should run a single script in background (`nohup`) with a loop and `sleep`

Comment: @krisFR thank you for the advice.  How would you write that in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your script is actually doing, maybe it requires a lot of server resources, and for sure the next one is starting before the previous one has finished. Is it what you want ? I will guess "no".

I would suggest to run a single `Bash` script, something like :

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
   /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myFile.php >> /var/www/html/cronlog 2> /dev/null
   sleep 10
done
```

Let's consider you put the above code in file `/home/me/myscript.sh` you can run it in background using :

```
nohup /home/me/myscript.sh &
```

Test and check if it feets your need.

Comment: thank you will try it out!  yes sometimes it requires a lot of server resource and preferably i would like the next one to start after the first process has finished

Comment: when you say `single script in background(nohup)` would this work for the cron? `*  *  *  *  * sudo /usr/local/bin/myScript.sh httpd /var/www/html/cronlog > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: It could but it is not my advice, it will be worst ! But warning, the sample script i've provided will execute the PHP script every 10 seconds after the previous one has finished : so, depending on the time your PHP script takes to execute, you can have more or less than 6 executions per minutes

Comment: i see,  can you recommend a better way of writing the cron please.

Comment: I've updated my answer. `Cron` is not necessarily the way to go. Ask yourself and adjust your initial question accordingly : "Do i want a straight number of execution per minutes ? if yes, how many ? What do i do if previous execution is not finished yet when next starts ?"